# How the $N/Z$ ratio affects the stability of isotopes and their method of radioactive decay?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy, isotopes

Although there is a graph that tells us the number of isotopes and which ones are stable or abundant in nature, like the one below, I have come across the $N/Z$ ratio, which is the number of neutrons divided by the number of protons, to determine isotopic stability.

[image]

Sources all point to the $N/Z$ ratio being the proportionate measure of the strong nuclear force and the electromagnetic force, which are the two sources that control the stability of the atomic nucleus.

How can we use the $N/Z$ ratio to determine an isotope's stability?  Does the $N/Z$ ratio tell us which isotopes are alpha-emitters, which are beta+ or beta- emitters?

Sorry that this is a lot. This question has been puzzling me for days now.

Comment: You are asking for large chunks of nuclear physics textbooks.

Comment: @JonCuster I've been researching online, but have not found any authoritative sources. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Weisskopf’s book is old, but inexpensive as a Dover reprint.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [the semi-empirical mass formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula) does a nice job of explaining the five terms in that approximation, including the $(N-Z)^2$ contribution to the energy. For magic numbers you have to progress to the [shell model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model), which has a *lot* in common with the electron shell model which structures the periodic table. I agree that the question in its current state (v1) is probably too broad to be answered appropriately here.

Comment: The first page to which @rob links has [a subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula#Examples_of_consequences_of_the_formula) with an especially relevant approximation of which nuclei are the most stable (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron%E2%80%93proton_ratio#Semi-empirical_description)).